# Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype bool | Adding mask in LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, masking

I wish to add my own created mask in LSTM. Here is my code:

```
    input_seq = Input(shape=(max_length, 1),name='input_layer')
    mask = Input(shape=(max_length,),name='mask_layer')
    
    lstm1 = LSTM(25,return_sequences=True)(inputs=input_seq,mask=mask)
    lstm2 = LSTM(25,return_sequences=True)(lstm1)
    dense1 = Dense(50,activation='relu')(lstm2)
    dense2 = Dense(10,activation='relu')(dense1)
    model=Model(inputs=[input_seq,mask],outputs=dense2)
    model.summary()
```

I am getting following error:

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype bool: <tf.Tensor 'SequenceMask/Less:0' shape=(None, None) dtype=bool>

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62839033/input-y-of-equal-op-has-type-bool-that-
does-not-match-type-float32-of-argume